# Start an alert dialog animation from a point in the screen

Tags: android, android-animation, android-alertdialog

I need to start an alert dialog, which is having animation, from a particular point in the screen. On a button click the alert dialog will appear with a fade_in animation and disappear with a fade_out animation. The dialog needs to enter from a particular point.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
 AlertDialog dialog = //create your Alert dialog here
 WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

 wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; //set preferred gravity
 wmlp.x = 300;   //x position
 wmlp.y = 300;   //y position

 dialog.setAttributes(wmlp);
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: How exactly it is not working? Did you specify the right coordinates?

Comment: Try adding horizontal gravity like so  wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;